# Relation between number of possible multisets of size k out of set of size n and number of k-letter strings out of alphabet of size n

Tags: combinatorics

I am self-studying combinatorics and just learned that there are (n+k-1 choose k) ways to select k-element multisets out of an n-element set.

However, I figured this out to be equal to the number of ways there are to construct k-element strings out of an alphabet of size n, except we don't care for order, so, n^k/k!.

This turns out to quite obviously not be the same. What mistake am I making?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "*This turns out to quite obviously not be the same*"  Quite.  $n^k/k!$ is not even going to be an integer most of the time, and as such can not possibly be the answer to a counting question.  "*What mistake am I making?*"  Thinking that $n^k/k!$ is an answer to a counting question.

Answer (score 1):

I just realised k! is overcounting the permutations of the string. "aab" can only be permuted four ways, not six.